# Adding a print statement speeds up code by an order of magnitude

Tags: c++, performance

I've hit a piece of extremely bizarre performance behavior in a piece of C/C++ code, as suggested in the title, which I have no idea how to explain.

Here's an as-close-as-I've-found-to-minimal working example [EDIT: see below for a shorter one]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

const int pp = 29;
typedef complex<double> cdbl;

int main() {
  cdbl ff[pp], gg[pp];
  for(int ii = 0; ii < pp; ii++) {
    ff[ii] = gg[ii] = 1.0;
  }

  for(int it = 0; it < 1000; it++) {
    cdbl dual[pp];

    for(int ii = 0; ii < pp; ii++) {
      dual[ii] = 0.0;
    }

    for(int h1 = 0; h1 < pp; h1 ++) {
      for(int h2 = 0; h2 < pp; h2 ++) {
        cdbl avg_right = 0.0;
        for(int xx = 0; xx < pp; xx ++) {
          int c00 = xx, c01 = (xx + h1) % pp, c10 = (xx + h2) % pp, 
              c11 = (xx + h1 + h2) % pp;
          avg_right += ff[c00] * conj(ff[c01]) * conj(ff[c10]) * gg[c11];
        }
        avg_right /= static_cast<cdbl>(pp);

        for(int xx = 0; xx < pp; xx ++) {
          int c01 = (xx + h1) % pp, c10 = (xx + h2) % pp, 
              c11 = (xx + h1 + h2) % pp;
          dual[xx] += conj(ff[c01]) * conj(ff[c10]) * ff[c11] * conj(avg_right);
        }
      }
    }
    for(int ii = 0; ii < pp; ii++) {
      dual[ii] = conj(dual[ii]) / static_cast<double>(pp*pp);
    }

    for(int ii = 0; ii < pp; ii++) {
      gg[ii] = dual[ii];
    }

#ifdef I_WANT_THIS_TO_RUN_REALLY_FAST
    printf("%.15lf\n", gg[0].real());
#else // I_WANT_THIS_TO_RUN_REALLY_SLOWLY
#endif

  }
  printf("%.15lf\n", gg[0].real());

  return 0;
}
```

Here are the results of running this on my system:

```
me@mine $ g++ -o test.elf test.cc -Wall -Wextra -O2
me@mine $ time ./test.elf > /dev/null
    real    0m7.329s
    user    0m7.328s
    sys     0m0.000s
me@mine $ g++ -o test.elf test.cc -Wall -Wextra -O2 -DI_WANT_THIS_TO_RUN_REALLY_FAST
me@mine $ time ./test.elf > /dev/null
    real    0m0.492s
    user    0m0.490s
    sys     0m0.001s
me@mine $ g++ --version
g++ (Gentoo 4.9.4 p1.0, pie-0.6.4) 4.9.4 [snip]
```

It's not terribly important what this code computes: it's just a tonne of complex arithmetic on arrays of length 29.  It's been "simplified" from a much larger tonne of complex arithmetic that I care about.

So, the behavior seems to be, as claimed in the title: if I put this print statement back in, the code gets a lot faster.

I've played around a bit: e.g, printing a constant string doesn't give the speedup, but printing the clock time does.  There's a pretty clear threshold: the code is either fast or slow.

I considered the possibility that some bizarre compiler optimization either does or doesn't kick in, maybe depending on whether the code does or doesn't have side effects.  But, if so it's pretty subtle: when I looked at the disassembled binaries, they're seemingly identical except that one has an extra print statement in and they use different interchangeable registers.  I may (must?) have missed something important.

I'm at a total loss to explain what an earth could be causing this.  Worse, it does actually affect my life because I'm running related code a lot, and going round inserting extra print statements does not feel like a good solution.

Any plausible theories would be very welcome.  Responses along the lines of "your computer's broken" are acceptable if you can explain how that might explain anything.

---

**UPDATE**: with apologies for the increasing length of the question, I've shrunk the example to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

const int pp = 29;
typedef complex<double> cdbl;

int main() {
  cdbl ff[pp];
  cdbl blah = 0.0;
  for(int ii = 0; ii < pp; ii++) {
    ff[ii] = 1.0;
  }

  for(int it = 0; it < 1000; it++) {
    cdbl xx = 0.0;

    for(int kk = 0; kk < 100; kk++) {
      for(int ii = 0; ii < pp; ii++) {
        for(int jj = 0; jj < pp; jj++) {
          xx += conj(ff[ii]) * conj(ff[jj]) * ff[ii];
        }
      }
    }
    blah += xx;

    printf("%.15lf\n", blah.real());
  }
  printf("%.15lf\n", blah.real());

  return 0;
}
```

I could make it even smaller but already the machine code is manageable.  If I change **five bytes** of the binary corresponding to the callq instruction for that first printf, to 0x90, the execution goes from fast to slow.

The compiled code is very heavy with function calls to __muldc3().  I feel it must be to do with how the Broadwell architecture does or doesn't handle these jumps well: both versions run the same number of instructions so it's a difference in instructions / cycle (about 0.16 vs about 2.8).

Also, compiling -static makes things fast again.

---

**Further shameless update**: I'm conscious I'm the only one who can play with this, so here are some more observations:

It seems like calling any library function — including some foolish ones I made up that do nothing — for the *first time*, puts the execution into slow state.  A subsequent call to printf, fprintf or sprintf somehow clears the state and execution is fast again.  So, importantly the first time __muldc3() is called we go into slow state, and the next {,f,s}printf resets everything.

Once a library function has been called once, and the state has been reset, that function becomes free and you can use it as much as you like without changing the state.

So, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  complex<double> foo = 0.0;
  foo += foo * foo; // 1
  char str[10];
  sprintf(str, "%c\n", 'c');
  //fflush(stdout); // 2

  for(int it = 0; it < 100000000; it++) {
    foo += foo * foo;
  }

  return (foo.real() > 10.0);
}
```

is fast, but commenting out line 1 or uncommenting line 2 makes it slow again.

It must be relevant that the first time a library call is run the "trampoline" in the PLT is initialized to point to the shared library.  So, maybe somehow this dynamic loading code leaves the processor frontend in a bad place until it's "rescued".

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour if you call `gg[0].real()` without the printf statement (in such a way that it doesn't get optimized away). I tried out your code, but didn't see the same behaviour on my system (both versions took the same time), but that is VM so may behave differently.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/DuAYHz, https://ideone.com/BY4GIq

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, both are almost exactly equally fast on my system (gcc6, 64 bit Linux). Can you provide more information about your setup?

Comment: Or try rebuilding the slow variant to make sure you don't accidentally use the wrong binary and then time it a couple of times, maybe your storage device (or the Kernel accessing it) lagged for a few seconds.

Comment: @TheDark: I tried changing the print to tot += gg[0].real() for some variable tot.  It goes back to the slow version.

Comment: @BaummitAugen It's a pretty standard 64 bit gentoo linux box, running gcc4.9.4 as posted above, glibc2.23-r3.  What extra information would be helpful?  I don't see much point dumping my processor specs all over the page unless it'd help.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I've been running variants of this all afternoon so by now I'd feel pretty silly if it were an oversight like that, but I've checked again and I'm pretty sure it's real.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that. "Optimizer bug" in your old version of gcc would be my next guess. If it isn't that either, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I've updated to g++ (Gentoo 5.4.0-r3 p1.3, pie-0.6.5) 5.4.0 and the behavior persists.  My system is pretty frightened of upgrading to gcc-6.*.*.

Comment: @FreddieManners You don't need to upgrade your entire system gcc, you can just compile the new version into your home folder and use it for the tests. Compiling gcc is pretty easy. Not too sure how much that would help though, gcc5 is reasonably new and your code is not ultra complex.

Comment: I guess it is thinkable at least that the Gentoo "packaged" version of gcc is somehow bodged, so the clean upstream source build may be worth a shot anyways. I'm not sure how that would happen, but while we are taking stabs in the dark...

Comment: I tried copying the compiled binaries that show a difference on my machine, to a virtual Ubuntu server far away, and ran them there.  They run in exactly the same amount of time.  So, I reckon the compiler's off the hook and it must be some weird operational issue.

Comment: I wonder if it is something to do with process priorities.  With the print, you periodically interrupt what is an otherwise compute-bound process with a system call.  This may make the o/s schedule your process more favourably than when it never does any system calls (so the kernel always preempts the process at the end of its time quantum, rather than part way through). I'm not sure what's the best way to analyze the process priority; maybe `top`, or via something in `/proc/<pid>` or …

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried some stuff.  The slow version seems to run with about 10 (say, 8 to 15) context switches over its 7s lifetime, according to /proc/<pid>/status.  So, that shouldn't cost.  (The faster version has about 2 which is roughly proportional.)  Also, changing the niceness from 0 (default) to -19 to 20 makes no difference.  The scheduler has 11 other logical processors to play with so I'd hope it would leave the program in peace...

Comment: Under my (very tentative) hypothesis, the fact that there are only 8-15 context switches is the trouble. The scheduler is set up to run processes that routinely need to use kernel services. Since your code doesn't, it is gradually given a lower priority, and made to wait more. Now, given that you have a 12 (logical) CPU machine, this becomes less plausible, but it depends in part on what else is going on on the machine as a whole. Is it suffering from overload? This could all be red herring territory (and if so, I'm sorry — I'm just trying to think out of the box a bit).

Comment: You might want to compare the context switches for your process with something like the shell (your login shell), or perhaps a running Awk script, or a Perl script.  The chances are good that those do more — many more — context switches than your program is showing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler At the moment the 12 logical / 6 physical processors are  otherwise (i) all idle almost all the time, (ii) all almost idle all the time, and (iii) almost all idle all the time.  "cat /proc/$$/status" (assuming that's what you meant?) shows a tonne of voluntary context switches but very few involuntary ones.  Also I'm being dumb, but doesn't fewer switches mean the scheduler is being nice to us?  Anyhow, red herring or not the ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: In that case (other CPUs mostly idle), my hypothesis probably isn't relevant — you'll have to wait for someone else to come up with a better one.  SOrry.

Comment: in dev TDM GCC 4.9.2 it taking less time without printf, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: @TanujYadav Right, my latest thinking is that this is happening below the level of machine code abstraction.  The machine code for my fast and slow versions differs almost not at all, so it seems to be a question of how the processor implements that code in practice.  That might be difficult to reproduce.

Comment: Do you use stock kernel or special one?

Comment: @Slava Stock, vmlinuz-4.4.26-gentoo .

Comment: You should try different versions of kernel.

Comment: If the processor you're running this on uses a global history for branch prediction, it's possible that you have some branches being mapped to the same branch table entry.  If those branches go in the opposite direction, then it could cause either or both branches to mispredict.  If you can change the data so that different branches are taken within __muldc3(), that may provide some clues.  Also, just out of interest, does the problem happen with array sizes other than 29?

Comment: @RichardByron Thanks for this.  If I change the complexes to 1.0/0.0, it changes the internal branches in __muldc3; and though there's a small time penalty for the extra work this causes, it doesn't alter the overall picture: the time penalty is small compared to the fast/slow shift.  Re 29: I think yes, and in particular the bottom code snippet above has no arrays at all.  Finally, I can't find source code for the __muldc3 that actually runs; replacing it with a homebrew version kills the effect.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, I finally figured this out.

It turns out this is to do with AVX–SSE transition penalties.  To quote [this exposition from Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-avx-sse-transition-penalties):

> When using Intel® AVX instructions, it is important to know that mixing 256-bit Intel® AVX instructions with legacy (non VEX-encoded) Intel® SSE instructions may result in penalties that could impact performance. 256-bit Intel® AVX instructions operate on the 256-bit YMM registers which are 256-bit extensions of the existing 128-bit XMM registers. 128-bit Intel® AVX instructions operate on the lower 128 bits of the YMM registers and zero the upper 128 bits. However, legacy Intel® SSE instructions operate on the XMM registers and have no knowledge of the upper 128 bits of the YMM registers. Because of this, the hardware saves the contents of the upper 128 bits of the YMM registers when transitioning from 256-bit Intel® AVX to legacy Intel® SSE, and then restores these values when transitioning back from Intel® SSE to Intel® AVX (256-bit or 128-bit). The save and restore operations both cause a penalty that amounts to several tens of clock cycles for each operation.

The compiled version of my main loops above includes legacy SSE instructions (`movapd` and friends, I think), whereas the implementation of `__muldc3` in libgcc_s uses a lot of fancy AVX instructions (`vmovapd`, `vmulsd` etc.).

This is the ultimate cause of the slowdown.
Indeed, Intel performance diagnostics show that this AVX/SSE switching happens almost exactly once each way per call of `__muldc3' (in the last version of the code posted above):

```
$ perf stat -e cpu/event=0xc1,umask=0x08/ -e cpu/event=0xc1,umask=0x10/ ./slow.elf

 Performance counter stats for './slow.elf':
    100,000,064      cpu/event=0xc1,umask=0x08/
    100,000,118      cpu/event=0xc1,umask=0x10/
```

(event codes taken from table 19.5 [of another Intel manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3b-part-2-manual.html)).

That leaves the question of why the slowdown turns on when you call a library function for the first time, and turns off again when you call `printf`, `sprintf` or whatever.  The clue is [in the first document again](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-avx-sse-transition-penalties):

> When it is not possible to remove the transitions, it is often possible to avoid the penalty by explicitly zeroing the upper 128-bits of the YMM registers, in which case the hardware does not save these values.

I think the full story is therefore as follows.  When you call a library function for the first time, the trampoline code in `ld-linux-x86-64.so` that sets up the PLT leaves the upper bits of the MMY registers in a non-zero state.  When you call `sprintf` among other things it zeros out the upper bits of the MMY registers (whether by chance or design, I'm not sure).

Replacing the `sprintf` call with `asm("vzeroupper")` — which instructs the processor explicitly to zero these high bits — has the same effect.

The effect can be eliminated by adding `-mavx` or `-march=native` to the compile flags, which is how the rest of the system was built.  Why this doesn't happen by default is just a mystery of my system I guess.

I'm not quite sure what we learn here, but there it is.

Comment: Is the any inline function to do `asm("vzeroupper")`, like the other `_mm256*` functions?